# Confirm password field not working

Tags: android

I am trying to match two field that is of password but its showing password do not match

```
 else if (_passwordText.getText().toString().equals("") || _passwordText.length() < 4 || _passwordText.length() > 10) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("oops!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Password  field is empty");
        alertDialog.show();
    }


   else if (_repasswordText.getText().toString().equals(_passwordText.getText().toString())) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("oops!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Passwords do not match");
        alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: You didn't negate the equality...

Comment: Also "field is empty" is a strange message for `length < 4 || length > 10`

Comment: @cricket_007 that is just to validate

Comment: @cricket_007 i am new to this stuff can u explain me

Comment: Validate what? Your code says `if (passwords_are_equal) { setMessage("do not match") }`

Comment: ohh yes...got it .

Comment: Anyways, if you are new to all this, you may be taking on more than you can handle. You seem to have made a logical mistake, and you should take more time to debug the code yourself instead of immediately heading to StackOverflow

Comment: before i was using 
        else if(repassword.getText().toString()!= password.getText().toString() )

Comment: but it again showed the same

Comment: Well, yes. You should learn basic Java first, probably, but that is not how you compare strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if (_passwordText.getText().toString().equals("")  {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("oops!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Password  field is empty");
        alertDialog.show();
    }


   else if (!_repasswordText.getText().toString().equals(_passwordText.getText().toString())) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("oops!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Passwords do not match");
        alertDialog.show();
        }
```

**FYI**

1. **At first check**  `equals("")`
2. Add `!` sign before  **_repasswordText.getText().toString()**

Answer (score 1):

You should add `!` before

```
_repasswordText.getText().toString().equals(_passwordText.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_repasswordText.getText().toString().contentEquals(_passwordText.getText().toString())`

Comment: Nope . Did you check his question ?